# Why DOM structure is not seen on source code?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, web-scraping

If i hit `right click->wiew source` on some websites (e.g keep.google.com) i can't see DOM. I get a buch of JavaScript instead of `<body><div>...</div></body>` structure. However if i go `right click->inspect element` i can reach DOM with Chrome Developer Tools.

1) Why i cannot access DOM from source code?

2) How can i access DOM programmatically?

I have looked some node.js tutorials but i don't know whether i am on the right way.

Comment: JavaScript is used to dynamically build DOM

Comment: There is no DOM in the source code.  Source code is literal text.  The Document Object Model is the object in the browser that is created from the initial source and modified after the fact.

Comment: @Taplar , ic3b3rg thank you both. Is there a way to access a specific element in pages with dynamically created?

Comment: Yes, many different ways.  If you are unfamiliar with that then you need to find a beginners tutorial to javascript.

Answer (score 2):

If your HTML is build dynamically with JavaScript the final HTML won't be shown in the original source from the server. But in the DevTools you will be able to inspect those dynamically created elements after they are created.

The `View Source` option shows the source directly from the server.

The `Inspect Element` option shows the current DOM including all dynamically created elements.

---

> Is there a way of getting a specific element from a dynamically created website by using for example JavaScript?

Without having some type of system to run that JavaScript code, and such, no not really. That is getting into a really complicated situation. That is why for SEO purposes dynamically created elements are still kinda discouraged. The big crawlers have learned how to detect those dynamically created elements by running the JavaScript code, then seeing the DOM result.

You could look into some type of headless browser system or something like that. But of course that could come with some security concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way of getting a specific element from a dynamically created website by using for example JavaScript?

Comment: @Tahtakafa I'm assuming you mean in terms of web scraping since your question is tagged as that. Without having some type of system to run that JavaScript code, and such, no not really. That is getting into a really complicated situation. That is why for SEO purposes dynamically created elements are still kinda discouraged. The big crawlers have learned how to detect those dynamically created elements by running the JavaScript code, then seeing the DOM result.

Answer (score 1):

Press the F12 key on your browser and it should open up the developer tools. Depending on the browser you are using, you'll have different tabs, one where you can debug your Javascript.

1) Instead of view source, hit '**Elements**' tab.
Right clicking on a specific element in the browser with this tab open and select the option to ***Inspect Element***, will take you to that element.

[image: HTML Elements/list of scripts, basically view source view]

2) To access the DOM programmatically (or debug your code), you should hit on the '**Sources**' tab.
You'll have to open the specific file and place debug points as applicable and hit F11 to go to the next point, F8 to next debug point and other things.

You can also add console.log() to see specific data points, without manually debugging.

[image: Debugger for Javascript]